# Files with apparent 86TB file size, how to shrink them?

Tags: linux, files, xfs, sparse-files

After extracting a zip, I have 8.6P in apparent size but only 728M on disk used. I did some checks and `hdparm --fibmap` shows that all the files have a huge `byte_offset: 94331430207488`.

I tried to use `fallocate -d`, `cp --sparse=never` but both keep the file with the same offset so, apparently, with the same size. Using filefrag shows that all of them only have one extent. And it's not a hardlink because the counter for `ls -il` is 1.

So the question, is how can I shink them to use and show only the real size?

Comment: If a file is sparse, than the real size of a file is much more than it's allocated size, that's normal and that's what makes the file sparse. So 8.6P *is* its "real" size. To show its *allocated* size use `ls -s` (or `ls -ls` to see both), it will be displayed in blocks. If you want to extract only its allocated data, you need to figure out an offset at which it begins in the file and dump that part with e.g. `dd skip=... count=...` to skip the sparse area. There is no system call to "copy only allocated part out of a sparse file" or "to truncate file at the front".

Comment: I tried the skip and count, the issue is that, then, I end up with two parts of the file and it doesn't work correctly. So, I'm not reading or using the right value for both. For example, I have one file with `logical_offset 23030134328` and `length 169` if I use that directly in dd, it fails. @NikitaKipriyanov

Comment: `dd` works in terms of *blocks*, the size of the block you set with `bs=<size>` parameter. By default it's 512 (as if you have `dd bs=512 ...`), but note that extents are in terms of *filesystem* block size which is likely 4096 or more; explore your filesystem to know. So in general you can only work with the granularity of filesystem blocks. You can set up `bs=1` and it will work with bytes, but that might be very slow (and could wear SSDs faster than you expect).